# Using quantum computers to calculate definite integrals?

Tags: quantum-algorithms

### Question

How would a quantum computer calculate a definite integral (without resorting to approximations) of a function?

### Motivation

According to a [post](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/433329/using-a-time-like-boundary-as-a-computer) of mine (in the context of classical field theory) seems to make the following premises:

1. One can always infer the value of a field at a point.
2. There can exist a Robinson Boundary Condition.
3. This (Klien-Gordon) field obeys Lorentz transformations.

The conclusion seems to be:

> Using classical calculations and the Robin boundary condition I show
>   that one calculate the anti-derivative of a function within time $2X$
>   (I can compute an integral below)
>
> $$\frac{2 \alpha}{\beta} e^{ \frac{\alpha}{\beta}X} \int_0^{X}   e^{-
>  \frac{\alpha}{\beta}\tau}  \tilde f_0(\tau) d \tau$$
>
> where $f_0$ is an arbitrary function whose integral above converges.

Note: It is unclear to me how a quantum computer would stimulate a classical field in a way which would tell you the definite integral?

Comment: I suggest to elaborate more. There is a VtC as unclear for your post.

Comment: @peterhsaysreinstateMonica is this better?

Comment: Yes, I think it will survive the vote (no new close vote is arrived).

Comment: So the field theory is not important for this question. You are just asking for an ordinary definite integral now with us being able to forget that this came from solving a pde

Comment: @AHusain Yes. I only mention the field theory for comparison purposes: time taken is $2X$ and the space of functions (to integrate) is not limited to the original space of solutions of the PDE (Klein Gordon Equation).

Comment: Can you elaborate on the non-usage of approximations? If the integral does not have an analytical solution, the only thing on can do is approximate. In addition, approximations can be applied to limit the error so that it is negligible compared to noise and measurement distribution.

Comment: @Minh did you check the link in "according to a post of mine"? The details are given there (in the long post).